# How do I only backup data for specific apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

I want to back up data for some apps on iOS without including several GB of pictures and operating system files. How do I do this?

The option to backup data by app is completely missing from iCloud or I was unable to find it, and it also appears to be missing in iTunes. Where is the option to do selective or partial backup?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: iOS version 11.2.6. I'm also willing to look into using third-party applications for this.

Answer (score 4):

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247):

## Choose which apps to back up

Many iOS apps automatically back up to iCloud after you install them. You can change which apps back up and remove existing backups from your storage. Use these steps on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.

### iOS 10.3 or later:

1. Go to `Settings > [your name] > iCloud`.
2. If you use iOS 11, tap `Manage Storage > Backups`. If you use iOS 10.3, tap `iCloud Storage > Manage Storage`.
3. Tap the name of the device that you're using.
4. Under `Choose Data to Back Up`, turn off any apps that you don't want to back up.
5. Choose Turn Off & Delete.

### iOS 10.2 or earlier:

1. Go to `Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage`.
2. Tap the name of the device that you're using.
3. Under `Backup Options`, turn off any apps that you don't want to back up.
4. Choose Turn Off & Delete.

**When you confirm that you want to Turn Off & Delete an app, it turns off iCloud Backup for that app and removes all of its information from iCloud.**

Some apps, like Voice Memos, are always backed up and you can't turn them off.

Comment: I checked that and the vast majority of the apps (including most of the ones I want to back up) are missing. Only a handful of non-default apps show up in the list.

Comment: If you didn't jailbreak your iPhone and you installed the apps from the App Store, those apps should be there.  Can you edit your question to include screenshots of that screen that's missing the apps?

Comment: I opened up the menu you mentioned and there's a list of apps. Almost all of the apps listed are default/built-in. The bottom section of the apps has a few downloaded (other-than-default) apps listed, and almost none of the ones I want to back up appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't related to icloud, but if you have jailbreaked device, you can use "Apps Manager" tweak (https://www.tigisoftware.com/default/?page_id=259) to locally backup/restore data by app. It works fine even on iOS 10 and 11